# How to get original requests in Alamofire 5?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I made a wrapper for Alamofire which makes the data request first and then it prints the details of original `URLRequest`.

```
let dataRequest = session.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters)
let originalRequest = dataRequest.request
// Now print somehow the details of original request.
```

It worked fine on Alamofire 4.9, but it stopped in the newest 5.0 version. The problem is that `dataRequest.request` is nil. Why this behavior has changed? How can I access `URLRequest` underneath `DataRequest`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`URLRequest`s are now created asynchronously in Alamofire 5, so you're not going to be able to access the value immediately. Depending on what you're doing with the `URLRequest` there may be other solutions. For logging we recommend using the new `EventMonitor` protocol. You can read [our documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#using-eventmonitors) to see more, but adding a simple logger is straightforward:

```swift
final class Logger: EventMonitor {
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: ...)

    // Event called when any type of Request is resumed.
    func requestDidResume(_ request: Request) {
        print("Resuming: \(request)")
    }

    // Event called whenever a DataRequest has parsed a response.
    func request<Value>(_ request: DataRequest, didParseResponse response: DataResponse<Value, AFError>) {
        debugPrint("Finished: \(response)")
    }
}

let logger = Logger()
let session = Session(eventMonitors: [logger])
```

Comment: I need to access .request in a test that I am maintaining – can I wait until it is populated somehow?

Comment: @de. Yes, you can add an `onURLRequestCreation` closure to your `Request`.

Answer (score 0):

I had to obtain the `URLRequest` in a test case. Solved it by adding `.responseData` and using `XCTestExpectation` to wait for the async code to return:

```
func testThatHeadersContainContentEncoding() {

    let exp = expectation(description: "\(#function)\(#line)")
    let request = AF.request("http://test.org",
                             method: .post, parameters: ["test":"parameter"],
                             encoding: GZIPEncoding.default,
                             headers: ["Other":"Header"])
    request.responseData { data in

        let myHeader = request.request?.value(forHTTPHeaderField: additionalHeader.dictionary.keys.first!)
        // .. do my tests
        exp.fulfill()
    }
    waitForExpectations(timeout: 10, handler: nil)
}
```